# Find if KeyUp or KeyDown event was fired

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a block of identical code for both the `KeyUp` and `KeyDown` events; the only difference is in one single line of code, which changes `button.BackColor` to `Color.Gray` or `Color.White` accordingly. I want to put this block of code into a separate method to avoid repetition, and the single line that is different for the two events should look like:

```
button.BackColor = (KeyUp was fired) ? Color.Gray : Color.White;
```

The method accepts `KeyEventArgs e` as a parameter, but I can't figure out how to determine whether `e` is of type `KeyUp` or `KeyDown`. In C# (winforms), is there an analog to `event.type` property in JavaScript? Otherwise, any other way to do this? Thanks

Comment: Is this winforms or WPF?, `KeyEventArgs` exists in both

Comment: Forgot to mention, this is winforms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way from the `System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs` to determine whether the event has been raised as the result of a `KeyUp` or `KeyDown` event. Your best bet would be to have different handling methods which both call a common method, i.e.

```
private void OnKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs eventArgs)
{
    HandleKeyState(false, eventArgs);
}

private void OnKeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs eventArgs)
{
    HandleKeyState(true, eventArgs);
}

private void HandleKeyState(bool isKeyUp, KeyEventArgs eventArgs)
{
    button.BackColor = isKeyUp ? Color.Gray : Color.White;
}
```

Comment: In a general case, is there a way in C# to determine the type of event that was fired? If so, how could I pass this info to a method, and how could that method make a decision based on the type of event?

Comment: It will always depend upon the class raising the event, it could either raise different events (i.e. `KeyDown`, `KeyUp`) or have a single event and set different values in their `EventArgs` implementation (i.e. `KeyInput` event with an `EventArgs` implementation with an `IsKeyDown` property). How you handle this in your code would be a choice up to you, in my answer I simply used a `bool` but you may wish to use an enum or construct your own type with the information you require.